# Package Size & Bundling of UWP applications

Tags: c#, upload, store, uwp

For UWP applications Microsoft recommends to bundle the application like this

> theapplication_1.0.0.0_x86_x64_arm_bundle.appxupload

The package includes a binary for x86, x64 and ARM. In theory the users only needs to download whatever fits his device.

One of my applications appxupload is about 45 Mb, with each of the binaries making up pretty much one third of the total size. Now, I would have expected downloads of around 15 Mb in the store on each platform, but ths is **not** the case. In fact I have to download all three binaries (45 Mb) on all platforms. I have tried this on the phone and on a desktop.

So I tried unbundling the binaries, but the store refuses to accept my upload:

[image]

**Question:**

How to make sure users only download the binary that their device requires?

Answer (score 1):

The appxupload needs to have everything your application needs to be compiled to .NET Native in the Store ingestion pipeline.

I'm a bit surprised that you're seeing all three architectures in your downloads from Store but without some more information (ex: the name of your app) I can't dig in any further. If you send a mail to dotnetnative@microsoft.com I'd be happy to help further.